# Problems with nvidia-settings and nvidia-xconfig

Tags: nvidia

When I start nvidia-settings it gives me:

> You do not appear to be using NVIDIA X driver. Please edit you X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.

Also, there are no settings available in this window.

When I ran nvidia-xconfig (as sudo), it generates this file:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 295.40  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06.nvidia.com)  Thu Apr  5 22:40:54 PDT 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    FontPath        "unix/:7100"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Then I reboot the system, and the only resolution available is somethink like 640x480 (far away from native 1600x900). If I restart X only the systems logs me out (login screen), gives crappy resolution and whenever I log on, it immediately logs me out again. To solve this, I installed gdm and reconfigured it. I have a different login-screen now, which is not the main problem.

(I surely deleted xorg.conf and rebooted to get my resolution back everytime it was fu**ed up)

Additional Drivers says: nvidia_current, with a note beneath it: This driver is activated but not currently in use.

System Settings > System > Details > Graphics says: Driver: Unknown, Experience: Standard

I use ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Graphics card: GeForce GT540M Cuda (tm) 1GB

I have tried to solve the problem every now and then and I get really frustrated with it. For not being able to play games with high settings, not being able to run an external Monitor (HDMI, TV) with a resolution higher than 5XX x 7XX and so on.

Need any more information?

Thanks in advance.

Additional information:

**Output of lspci | grep VGA is**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: What is the output of `lspci | grep VGA`?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed, Sven?  I have the exact same problem with the exact same card.

Answer (score 6):

Are you really sure you deleted `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`? Without it the system should be back to normal... Either way there's [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8750917&postcount=2) post that suggests running this command to reconfigure Xorg:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
```

Also you should remove the nVidia driver. Your system seems to have Optimus technology, so you can't install the nVidia driver the same way you would in a normal system. If it was installed through apt-get/Software Center this should remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
```

If you want to disable your nVidia card (to save some power) and use it to run some specific programs (like games) you should try [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/).
You can find more info on how to install it/debug problems on [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) or here at AskUbuntu.

Hope this helps.